# Eclipse randomly stopped starting

Tags: eclipse, java

I've been using Eclipse a lot recently, and haven't had any problems with it. Last night, I was working on it perfectly fine. However, this morning, whenever I load it up, the program stops working half way the loading splash screen (before the actual workspace opens up). The information says "Loading Workbench" and just stays there forever. When I click on it multiple times, I get a message saying that Java(TM) Platform SE binary is not responding.

Google hasn't been a ton of help, and seems to just give a lot of responses about Minecraft. I'm slightly confused as to where I need to start looking, since nothing had changed since I successfully used it last. No updates to Java or Eclipse or anything else. Thanks for the help, and let me know if you need any more information!

Comment: Try a re install or check if there is any problem with the java which has been installed. Was any settings changed when u worked the last time ?

Comment: Since Eclipse is written in Java it should be possible to get a Thread dump (e.g. using jstack) and determine exactly what is blocked. That might give you more specific information for your google query

Comment: Looking at stack traces could be useful towards raising a bug at bugs.eclipse.org.  The simplest thing to try before reinstalling would be to run "eclipse -clean".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was actually able to fix it by just renaming my WorkSpace to WorkSpace1. Apparently it got corrupted somehow, and with the rename Eclipse was able to recreate a new one. Here's the link that helped me out:

http://spacetech.dk/eclipse-failed-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-805306369.html

Answer (score 3):

Two things to check when you have problems with Eclipse:

1. First, always check the `.log` file, located in the `.metadata` directory (`<workspace path>/.metadata/.log`) of your **workspace** (not the Eclipse installation directory). Keep in mind that this is a hidden file under Linux or Mac OS. It usually contains the exception that is causing the crash. I usually delete any existing `.log` file before firing up Eclipse, just to make sure I am looking at the relevant log entries (the file will be recreated at startup).
2. If #1 does not help, you can try deleting the `.metadata` directory altogether. It will be recreated on startup (this is basically what you did by changing the workspace). In my experience with Eclipse, I noticed that some files can get corrupted inside `.metadata`, making Eclipse act weirdly. Keep in mind that this directory contains customizations you made in Eclipse and its plugins for the workspace and you might need to make them again.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse tends to be weird sometimes. If you move stuff around outside of the directories it was initially installed in, it usually won't load. I don't know if that's what you did, but your best bet is to back up your workspace, and reinstall eclipse. I'm sure that will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try a reinstall if possible or else, check the eclipse error log, which would be present at'**/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/log**'.

This will help you knowing the problem.