# Why eclipse javaEE not response?

Tags: eclipse, windows-10

I was working on my  dynamic web project from 2 month .... today I close my eclipse and every thing was working fine ... now I open my eclipse and run my dynamic web project But the eclipse not response .... what happen and how I can fix the problem ? 
Edit : when the eclipse not response I close it when I close it the massage appare java (TM) DR binary is not responsing

Comment: have you checked eclipse startup logs? https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_can_I_find_that_elusive_.log_file%3F

Comment: Please edit your question and share more information. What means the eclipse not respond? Run button doesn't do anything? The server doesn't start? Does it show any crash?

Comment: when I run my dynamic web project it run but when I press any key in my project then eclipse became Not response ... the server start and the page loaded But when I press any key on my page then eclipse not response

Comment: I edit my question

Comment: Can you execute the server outside Eclipse? E.g. If you are using Tomcat run bin/startup.bat without open Eclipse and test your app. If it doesn't work try creating a new server instance. If it works the problem is with Eclipse. Ensure you are using the same jre in both test. Maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015636/eclipse-randomly-stopped-starting